# Zuul API GW as a docker container vs. as part of a Java Spring application?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm breaking my monolith application into a set of microservices written in Java Spring. As part of my microserivce architecture, I'm implementing some basic patterns such as service discovery, API gateway and more.
I implemented my API gateway as a Spring boot application using the "@EnableZuulProxy", which is part of the Spring cloud project.
My questions are:

1. what is the difference between my implementation and using the Zuul docker
   image off the shelf?
2. What are the cons and pros of each approach?

Comment: What is "Zuul docker container"?

Comment: I meant Zuul docker image (fixed it in the question). You can find the image in docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/r/netflixoss/zuul/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely there are no difference, if you use your Zuul API Gateway as jar or Docker container. In both cases, it plays the role of API Gateway.

There are difference in Ops (from DevOps), how you build, check, destroy and publish, control number of instances and so on.

If you chose the Docker as the main part of your infrastructure, and manage it using Docker Swarm, Mesos & Marathon, Kubernetes, Nomad or so on, then wrap your API Gateway to Docker.

If you run your Docker containers by the hand, using a console and `docker run` command, you can leave the API Gateway as jar build. But then, you loose all benefits of containerization.

Answer (score 0):

The both solutions provide the support for balancing between instances of your application.

The main difference is :

- **Zuul API GW** :

  - can not launch automatically new instance (you should scale manually)
  - no need to containerize your application
- **Docker container orchestrator** (Docker Swarm, Kubernetes ...) has the ability to scale automatically (launch new instance when it needs to be)